# How to extract multiple string occurences between two matching patterns using sed or grep commands

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I am newbie to unix and playing around with sed and awk commands. 
My sample snort rule has multiple occurrences of keyword "content". I need to extract all data between content:" and "; to a file.

This sample contains one rule in single line. My actual file contains 30k of such rules.

1rule file contains

```
alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"APP-DETECT Absolute Software Computrace outbound connection - search.namequery.com"; flow:to_server,established; content:"Host|3A| search.namequery.com|0D 0A|"; fast_pattern:only; http_header; content:"TagId: "; http_header; metadata:policy security-ips drop, ruleset community, service http; reference:url,absolute.com/support/consumer/technology_computrace; reference:url,www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-09/ORTEGA/BHUSA09-Ortega-DeactivateRootkit-PAPER.pdf; classtype:misc-activity; sid:26287; rev:4;) cat 4rules|sed 's/.*content:"\([^";]*\)".*/\1/'sdfjklhaskl;jdf;kljasdfsjkdfhnkl;asdjfklasdfja'sjkdsdfh;askldjf`
```

**Expected output:**

```
Host|3A| search.namequery.com|0D 0A|

TagId

\([^
```

I tried my with sed and grep commands.

```
grep -Po '(?<=content:").*(?=";)' 1rule
sed  's/.*content:"\([^";]*\).*/\1/' 1rule
```

The output I got is  not as expected:

Using grep, I could see all contents but there is intermediate data between them
sed gives me the last occurrence in a line along with non matching lines after the occurrence.

Please tell me know how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Why you don't want the text between `:"` and `";` in this `:"APP-DETECT Absolute Software Computrace outbound connection - search.namequery.com";`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj : Right now I was trying to extract the strings enclosed between keyword content:" and "; because Snort(intrusion detection system) compares the content strings against the incoming packets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `grep` (as in your question, taking advantage of the `-P` option for Perl-compatible regular expressions):

```
grep -Po 'content:"\K[^"]+' 1rule
```

- `\K` drops what's been matched so far: the field label and the opening `"`.
- `[^"]+` then matches the content of the string up to, but excluding, the closing `"`.

---

Alternatively, try `awk` with the following:

```
awk -F'content:' '{ 
    for (i=2;i<=NF;++i) {
      split($i, a, /"/); print a[2]
    }
  }' 1rule
```

- Splits the input line(s) into fields by separator `content:`
- Loops over files starting with index 2 (because field 1 is the string *preceding* the first `content:` substring).
- Splits the field into tokens by `"` and prints the 2nd token, which is the string enclosed in `"..."` at the start of the field.

Comment: This is perfect. Just as i needed.. Thank you. 
Could you suggest some good references to quickly learn awk

Comment: @Venkat: I'm glad to hear it. I have no specific references to recommend, but I can tell you how _I_ learned: reading `man awk` and studying answers here on SO. There are many skilled `awk` programmers here, such as [@Ed Morton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)

Comment: @mklement0 I realise I'm late to the party, but I was struggling to make `sed` do this, but then along comes `grep -P` - thanks!