# Using grep to extract multiple matchings in a line

Tags: regex, grep

I am working on data extraction from an html document with various `<p...>data data</p>` in the same line. I want to extract the data in each paragraph on a new line. How can I do this? I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234949/how-to-extract-multiple-string-occurences-between-two-matching-patterns-using-se) but the problem here is that it specifies the end with a single character and does not work with a set of characters.

Example:

```
<p...> data1 <b>imp</b> data2 </p>
```

should give me `data1 <b>imp</b> data2` but instead gives `data1` as it catches < of the bold tag.

**EDIT** : Here is one more example:
`<p class="cb-col cb-col-90 cb-com-ln">Aniket Choudhary to Warner, <b>SIX</b>, .. and Warner makes the most of the free-hit.</p>` should give me `Aniket Choudhary to Warner, <b>SIX</b>, .. and Warner makes the most of the free-hit.`

Comment: you'd be better off using html/xml parser instead of trying to solve this using grep... in any case, add some more variations of your input and expected output so that suggested solution could test them..

Comment: Something to work with: `grep -Eo '<p[^>]*>(.+)</p>'`

Comment: You could replace all opening `<p>` and closing `</p>` tags with newlines using **Perl** like this: `perl -lpe 's|<p[\s>]|\n|g; s|</p>|\n|g' SomeFile.html`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming GNU grep (Mac users have BSD grep, and this will not work):

```
grep -Poz '<p[^>]*>\K[\S\s]*?(?=<\/p>)'
```

This finds `<p...>` and then "forgets" it due to `\K`. Then it matches *slowly* until it reaches the `</p>`. If your `<p>...</p>` blocks are going to be very large, this will take a long time to accomplish.

The reason for the `-o` flag is to return "**o**nly" the text you want.

The reason for the `-z` flag is so that it doesn't stop at the end of each line; it instead considers each input to go until it finds a null. If your text contains newlines between `<p>` and `</p>`, this should try to find it.

Caveat: `<p>...stuff here...<p>this here</p>...more here...</p>` will return

```
...stuff here...<p>this here
```

since it doesn't test that the first `<p>` may contain nested `<p>`'s.